# Unity InjectionFactory Doesn't Run

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, nlog

Summary: It seems like the InjectionFactory is not being run for a type mapping. I'd like to know why and how to solve the problem.

At first, I tried to register the interface

```
Container.RegisterType<ILogger>(new InjectionFactory((c, t, n) => {
                return LogManager.GetLogger(n);
            }));
```

And resolve using the service locator

```
ServiceLocator.GetInstance<ILogger>("Operation Manager");
```

This resulted in

```
The current type, NLog.ILogger, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

After some tinkering, I decided to try a different approach and registered the service using the concrete type instead

```
Container.RegisterType<Logger>(new InjectionFactory((c, t, n) => {
                    return LogManager.GetLogger(n);
                }));
```

And changed the resolution method to

```
public OperationService([Dependency("Operation Service")]Logger logger)
```

This results in the following error:

```
 The type Logger does not have an accessible constructor.
```

The only reason I can think of for this behavior is if the function I've passed via the InjectionFactory isn't actually being called to resolve the object.

Comment: You are trying to resolve a dependency by name, i.e., "Operation Manager". But when you register you don't use this name.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm trying to resolve an object based on the name given to the "Resolve" method on the container by providing a custom method for creating the instance. LogManager.GetLogger(name) takes the name of the logger to be returned. I want to create the instance by passing the resolution name to the GetLogger method.

Comment: Are you by any chance talking about Microsoft's Unity? That is, not the Unity3D game engine whose tag you've used for your question?

Comment: @Bart Yes. This is not the game engine. This is the Dependency Injection Framework.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ah,  you mean the game engine. This is not about that. There's an unfortunate name collision happening here.

Comment: Tags are now fixed. I didn't see the "3d" part in the tag. Please excuse me.

Comment: ahhh@  thanks, @ginkner !!  understood!  that sounds like a fascinating system, BTW!

Comment: It isn't an answer to your question, but an alternative approach - http://davidkeaveny.blogspot.se/2011/03/unity-and-log4net.html. This way you can setup log4net with buildtracking instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you registered the type without a name, and you're trying to resolve it by name. Unity looks for a registration for `(ILogger, "Operation Manager")`, but it can't find any. Your registration with no name is never considered an eligible candidate, so the `InjectionFactory` is not called.

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to achieve what you're trying to do. It might be possible with a custom extension, but my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It would help if there was any useful documenation on unity at all. The injection factory LOOKS like it takes a function that takes a name parameter, but the way it's set up it doesn't look like there's any way to actually feed it that parameter.